# FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I haven't found any question like this on here so I wanted to ask. Please keep in mind that I'm new to Fragments & FragmentActivity (not Android) and I don't really know how to work with them quite yet but I'm learning. My question is I want to know how to change from a FragmentActivity to a Fragment so I can incorporate it into my app seamlessly without any errors. The code I want to rid errors of is below

```
   public class Work extends Fragment implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Tattoos", "Piercings", "Social Networks" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.our_work);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

}
```

I've tried 3 different ways of doing this by rearranging the code but nothing works. Please help me with this!

**EDIT** I've tried it this way now

```
public class Work extends Fragment implements
ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private String[] tabs = { "Tattoos", "Piercings", "Social Networks" };

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
rootView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.our_work, container, false);

// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
actionBar = getActionBar();
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

// Adding Tabs
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
            .setTabListener(this));
}

/**
 * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
 * */
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // on changing the page
        // make respected tab selected
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }
});
}

return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
// on tab selected
// show respected fragment view
viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

first of all;

a `Fragment` must be inside a `FragmentActivity`, that's the first rule,

a `FragmentActivity` is quite similar to a standart `Activity` that you already know, besides having some Fragment oriented methods

second thing about Fragments, is that there is one important method you MUST call, wich is `onCreateView`, where you inflate your layout, think of it as the `setContentLayout`

here is an example:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView       = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);


    return mView;
}
```

and continu your work based on that mView, so to find a `View` by id, call `mView.findViewById(..);`

---

for the `FragmentActivity` part:

the xml part "must" have a `FrameLayout` in order to inflate a fragment in it

```
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  >
        </FrameLayout>
```

as for the inflation part

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new YOUR_FRAGMENT, "TAG").commit();

---

begin with these, as there is tons of other stuf you must know about fragments and fragment activities, start of by reading something about it (like life cycle) at the android developer site